# JavaFX Listview stacking data on 1 bar

Tags: listview, javafx

I am trying to make it so when i press a button an item from one list view will transfer to another but when i try to transfer 2 or more things it overlaps and removes the first selection. The task i have is that i have two lists a snack and a drinks list and a order list. i want to make it so i press a button and the item selected is transferred to the order list but when i click add it adds one item but when i add another it goes over the first item.

Here is the code,

```
public Button confirmOrder;
public Button add;
@FXML
private ListView<String> snacklist;
@FXML
private ListView<String>drinklist;
@FXML
private ListView<String>orderlist;


private Film currentFilm;








@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    snacklist.getItems().addAll("Crisps","Chips","PopCorn");
    snacklist.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    drinklist.getItems().addAll("Pepsi","Coke","Water");
    drinklist.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    orderlist.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);





    if(currentFilm != null){
        currentFilm = Main.getCurrentFilm();
    }






}





public void ConfirmOrderClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    //1 get chosen film from table

    //2 put the film onto the main classuing setter.
    Main.getCurrentFilm();
    Window mainWindow = confirmOrder.getScene().getWindow();
    Parent newRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Checkout.fxml"));
    mainWindow.getScene().setRoot(newRoot);
}


public void addsnack(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    orderlist.setItems(snacklist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    orderlist.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
}

public void addDrink(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    orderlist.setItems(drinklist.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    orderlist.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
}
```

}

Comment: anyway, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: no new account plus not the other part

Comment: okay, should have checked :) But then you know the drill from your other questions, please comply to the suggestions that you received more than once!